# Android - How would I access a variable within the onTouch method for use in ViewFlipper

Tags: android, viewflipper, touch-event

I have a variable within a loop that i am changing whenever i touch on a button. i need this variable at the very end of the activity for setting which view for my viewflipper to display. This whole thing started because i kept getting the 'non-final variable inside an inner class defined in a different method' error. so i was looking on here and did as some people suggested - make a local final variable then reassign within the onTouch method. See code below:

```
for(int categoryIndex = 0; categoryIndex <menuCategories.size(); categoryIndex++){

        final CustomButton menuButton = new CustomButton(this);
        menuButton.setId(ViewIdentification.getId());
        menuButton.setText(menuCategories.get(categoryIndex).category_name);
        menuButton.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 77, 30, 16));
        menuButton.setTextSize(35);
        menuButton.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        menuButton.setTypeface(tf);
        menuButton.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        menuButton.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);

        sideMenu.addView(menuButton);

        final int currentCategoryIndex = categoryIndex;
        menuButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                myCurrentCategory = currentCategoryIndex;
                Log.d("Touched Side Menu button ", menuButton.getId() + ": " + menuButton.getText().toString());
                Log.d("My Current Category is ", Integer.valueOf(myCurrentCategory).toString());


                return false;
            }
        });
........
.......
.......building more stuff within this loop
```

In this loop i am building up an array of LinearViews that contain a number of RelativeViews(which of course have any number of views inside that). Since i have all these LinearViews i created a viewflipper to add all of these linear views then depending on what myCurrentCategory is will be what i set my flipper to. See Code Below:

```
    ViewFlipper flipper = new ViewFlipper(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams viewFlipperLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,  LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    viewFlipperLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, sideMenu.getId());
    viewFlipperLayoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 100, 0);
    //subMenuLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL, screenLayout.getId());
    flipper.setLayoutParams(viewFlipperLayoutParams);

    for(int flipperIndex = 0; flipperIndex < subMenuLinearLayouts.size(); flipperIndex++){
        flipper.addView(subMenuLinearLayouts.get(flipperIndex));
    }

    //set which part of the menu we want to see
    flipper.setDisplayedChild(myCurrentCategory);
```

One subMenuLinearLayout is a LinearLayout with relativelayouts with those relativelayouts having other views(as i explained before but wanted to be clear).

Just to note i have defined myCurrentCategory at the top of the program so it is globally defined. When i set it to known states 0,1,2,3,4,5, the ViewFlipper correctly shows me the correct LinearLayout...so i know this works. However inside the onTouch method where i am assigning a new value to myCurrentCategory based on the categoryIndex the ViewFlipper does not flip to that view. My log statements that i have show that the myCurrentCategory variable in question is even getting the right values. I have just tested it. So it boils down to why is the ViewFlipper not 'seeing' the change in the variable? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the correct output in your Log message in `onTouch`. But how should your ViewFlipper know that you just changed the content of a variable (onTouch happens at some random point in the future)?

You need to call some method in `onTouch` (e.g. `flipper.setDisplayedChild`) to see something.

> So it boils down to why is the ViewFlipper not 'seeing' the change in the variable? thanks!

Java / ViewFlipper does not monitor variables for you just because you used that variable at some point. In fact the code does not even know what variable you used. It just gets a new value.

Comment: doesn't everything within the activity constantly refresh? I figured since every action/view/ within each activity was always waiting for responses - so i assumed(wrongly evidently) when an something changed in the future all the set methods like set(variableName) would change on the next refresh. i hope that makes sense. i am going to try your suggestion and i will be back to respond.

Comment: The variable itself should be updated properly, I think what we doubt is that you're properly executing the ViewFlipper code again. But we can't tell without the full activity code, I don't think. At the very least the ViewFlipper related code.

Comment: i added additional code to the flipper code - it is at the very bottom of the activity where i am putting together all the pieces before setting them to the screen.. outside of the loop with the onTouch.

Comment: ok well i feel stupid. i have all this time been thinking of an activity as being completely linear. that is in this case i add all my built up views in my viewflipper but i guess when i was writing the code i had the mindset that it wouldn't know what views I had already added to it. So i did as zapi suggested. thanks again for the help.

Comment: There are some linear parts, for example `onCreate` is executed before `onResume` and so on. But once `onResume` is finished the App kind of pauses and waits for events to happen. To handle all those you have these `onTouch`, `onClick` and other onEvent handlers. The code you put in there is then executed whenever Android detects such an event. And it's your task to tell the UI that you want to have something changed. And it does not work otherwise: for example a method that takes an `int` cannot see changes you make to that variable because the method gets a copy of the value.